# How to match a string containing newline in mediawiki box?

Tags: python, regex

I use python and I have string looks likes this:

```
anything include {{infobox notperson anything include new line}}
anything
{{infobox person anything
many new lines and any charachter
}}
anything include {{infobox notperson anything include new line}}
```

and I want to regexp which get the whole **infobox person** area from **{{infobox person** to the first **}}** characters which is the end of infobox area.What regexp should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `re.DOTALL` flag in order to let `.` match a line break: https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL

And this is the regexp you're looking for:

```
re.compile("\{\{infobox person[^\}]*\}\}",re.DOTALL)
```

**edit:** as Jerry pointed out, no need to use `DOTALL` since `[^\}]` already matches the line breaks.

Comment: it works but is there any non python ,regexp only way?